# Firebase functions query is too slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently using Node with firebase-functions v. 3.16.0 and there's a huge performance issue with one of my functions (it's about 35-40 seconds for a cold start and 25-30 for subsequent queries). In essence, I'm trying to access the firestore database with ~50000 of records and get a couple of them, where the userId = userId provided. The very same query on the firebase console gives me results after like 30ms. I've tried multiple solutions, but most of them were more about the cold start time, although my function is slow even without a cold start. There's a chunk of code that causes that huge latency:

```
  const checkInsRef = db.collection(CHECKINS_COLLECTION);
  const checkInsSnapshot = await checkInsRef.where(USER_ID, '==', userId).get();
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you with this, but could we get some context on the collection's structure and that of its documents, as well as some context for where you're calling the query in JS? It might seem a little silly, but knowing the context really helps picture where the problems might lie, otherwise it's like throwing darts in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue myself. So, basically, even though the collection of User objects wasn't that big anyways (2MB), every user had a nasty object with  many nested object (sometimes like 7 nesting levels), making a collection duplicate without this "Payment" field and querying it gave me 4s on average

Comment: Nested objects and not nested documents? Because if it's nested documents that shouldn't be an issue unless you've got an index for each level of nesting... At least according to [this](https://youtu.be/Ofux_4c94FI?t=256)